# GASでスプレッドシートを参照し、特定の行を取得する

Tags: google-apps-script

GASでスプレッドシートの特定の列を取得しようとしています。
特定の列とは、下記のような表のうち、「num」が最大値の行のデータです。

| num | user | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Aさん | こんにちは |
| 3 | Bさん | ハロー |
| 4 | Cさん | Hello |

この表から、numが最大値の行=4のnum,user,textの値を取得するにはどのようなコードを書いたらいいでしょうか。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

この場合、下記のようなBuilt-in functionでの出力はいかがでしょうか。

```
=SORTN(A2:C,1,,1,)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

または、`google-apps-script`のタブから、Google Apps Scriptを使用する必要がある場合は、下記のようなサンプルスクリプトはいかがでしょうか。

```js
function sample() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // シート名を入れてください。
  const srcValues = sheet.getRange("A2:C" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const res = srcValues.sort((a, b) => a[0] < b[0] ? 1 : -1)[0];
  console.log(res); // <--- [ 4, 'Cさん', 'Hello' ]
}
```

どちらのサンプルも列Aで降順ソートを行い、最初の行を取得しています。

#### 参考:

- [SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: ありがとうございました、やりたいことができました！